# While extracting a value from Oracle (using Python) it's precision is getting lost

Tags: python, oracle, dataframe, precision, data-loss

I am looking to load a high-precision value from Oracle to Snowflake. I am doing this by first extracting the value from the oracle in a CSV file through a Python Script and then Loading it in Snowflake DB. What I am finding is that the value is not getting extracted the same as the value in oracle. I see some issues with the precision. I am not sure if this is something to do with the issue in Oracle (Version 19.12.0.0.0) or the Python Script (V 3.7). Note that this behavior is for a large set of values and the above is the design I need to follow for loading.

Value in Oracle DB: 86525.200000000006. This is available in a column of data type ‘number(28,12)’

Value in the extracted CSV File: 86525.2

What I have tried already:

#1. Converted the number to Char as below:

select value1 ,cast(value1 as varchar2(1000))

from table1

here the Value1 is coming as ‘86525.2’

#2.

TO_CHAR(value1 ,'fm9999999999999999.999999999999'),

here the Value is coming as ‘86525.2’

#3.
TO_CHAR(value1 ,'fm9999999999999999.000000000000'),

here the Value is coming as ‘86525.200000000000’

#4.
(SUBSTR (value1 , INSTR (value1 , '.',1))) mydecimal,

here the Value is coming as ‘86525.2’

#5.
to_number(regexp_replace(to_char(value1), '^[0-9]+.', '')) rexp,

here the Value is coming as ‘86525.2’

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the CSV file; the Oracle `CREATE TABLE` statement; the code you are using to read the CSV file and `INSERT` the data into the Oracle table; the python code you are using read the data from Oracle. The error could be in any of those and we need a [MRE] to be able to replicate the issue and see at what level the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use the default data type for `NUMBER` which is the Python `float`, that is responsible for the precision lost.

You must switch to the use of the `Decimal`data type which has a better precision.

As [documented](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html) you must define an *output type handler* that makes the conversion to `Decimal` in the `cursor`.

**Example**

The table from [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70606367/4808122) is used.

```
def number_to_decimal(cursor, name, default_type, size, precision, scale):
    if default_type == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_NUMBER:
        return cursor.var(decimal.Decimal, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.outputtypehandler = number_to_decimal

cursor.execute("select val from test" )

for val in cursor:
    print("Type  :", type(val[0]))
    print("Values:", val[0])
```

Output

```
Type  : <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
Values: 86525.200000000006
```

Answer (score 0):

Value is correctly stored into the table:

Sample data:

```
SQL> create table test (val number(28, 12));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (86525.200000000006);

1 row created.
```

Contents:

```
SQL> select * From test;

       VAL
----------
   86525,2             --> not all decimals here
```

Set column format:

```
SQL> col val format 99990d000000000000
SQL> select * From test;

                VAL
-------------------
 86525,200000000006             --> correct!

SQL>
```

---

`to_char` works as well:

```
SQL> select to_char(val, '99990d000000000000') result from test;

RESULT
-------------------
 86525,200000000006

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And, sorry if I didn't make my query clear enough. Please note that we are calling it from Python. I see this works fine in Oracle but doesn't when called from Python Script.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Python.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
y= decimal(1)/decimal(3)
print(type(y))
print(y)
```

**Output:**
`<class 'decimal.Decimal'> 0.333333333333333333333333`

You can place your value in `decimal(value)` and then proceed.